# Exception error in java maze program

Tags: java

Hey im new to java and im trying to write a program that solves a maze. but when run the program i keep getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at assignment4b.Maze.<init>(Maze.java:38)
    at assignment4b.Question5.main(Question5.java:10)
```

**Line 38** is where it says

> assert (readFile) != null;

AND **line 10** is where it says

> Maze m = new Maze("Maze.txt");

This is how the file im reading from looks like:

```
  20 7  Number of columns and rows 
    0 18  Exit square (rows and columns start at 0)
    6 12  Entrance square 
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX X 
    X            XXXX  X 
    X XXXXX XXXXX   XX X 
    X XXXXX XXXXXXX XX X 
    X            XX XX X
    X XXXXXXXXXX XX    X 
    XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
```

This is how my  main looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Question5 
    {
        public static void main (String[]args)
        {
            // Construct the maze
            Maze m = new Maze("Maze.txt");
            //System.out.println(m);

            while (!m.isOut())
            {
                    // input from the keyboard
                    int move;
                    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.print("Your move (1:north, 2:west, 3:east, 4:south, 5:help): ");
                    move = kb.nextInt();

                    System.out.println();

                    // Process the player's selection
                    switch (move)
                    {
                    case '1':
                        m.goNorth();
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        m.goWest();
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        m.goEast();
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        m.goSouth();
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        m.showPath(System.out);
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                    }


                    // Display the new maze (unless help was selected)
                    if (move != 5)
                    {
                        System.out.print(m);
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how my Maze Class looks like:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maze implements MazeInterface
{

        public static final int CLEAR = 0;
        public static final int WALL = 1;
        public static final int VISITED = 2;
        public static final int PATH = 3;

        private int row;
        private int col;
        // 2D array to represent the maze (on the heap)
        private int[][] maze;

        // entrance and exit points of the maze
        private Location entrance = new Location();
        private Location exit = new Location();

        // Location of the creature
        private Location creature = new Location();

        public Maze(String filename)
        {


                //innitialize maze
               // maze =  col<row<ReadFile>>();
               // input >> col >> row;

                //print path of file
                //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                Scanner readFile = new Scanner (filename);

                assert (readFile) != null;
               row = readFile.nextInt();
               col= readFile.nextInt();       
            // row and col must be positive
            assert(row>0 && col>0);

         // Dump the rest of the line
            while(readFile.hasNextLine());

                // Maze exit
                exit.r = readFile.nextInt();
                 exit.c = readFile.nextInt();

                // exit.r and exit.c must be between row and col
                assert(exit.r>=0 && exit.r<row);
                assert(exit.c>=0 && exit.c<col);

            // Dump the rest of the line
            while(readFile.hasNextLine());

                // Maze exit
                exit.r = readFile.nextInt();
                 exit.c = readFile.nextInt();

                // exit.r and exit.c must be between row and col
                assert(exit.r>=0 && exit.r<row);
                assert(exit.c>=0 && exit.c<col);

                // Maze entry
                entrance.r = readFile.nextInt();
                entrance.c = readFile.nextInt();
                // entrance.r and entrance.c must be between row and col
                assert(entrance.r>=0 && entrance.r<row);
                assert(entrance.c>=0 && entrance.c<col);


                // Dump the rest of the line
                while(readFile.hasNextLine());


                // Maze structure
                // Create the maze on the heap: 2D array of row*col ints
                maze = new int[row][col];
                for(int i=0; i<row; ++i)
                    maze[i] = new int[col];

                // Read the maze line by line
                String mazeLine;
                for(int r=0; r<row; ++r)
                {
                    // eof must not have been reached
                    assert(readFile != null);
                    mazeLine=readFile.toString();

                    for(int c=0; c<col; ++c)
                    {
                        // mazeline must be made of 'X' and ' ' only
                        assert(mazeLine.charAt(c) ==' ' || mazeLine.charAt(c) =='X');
                        maze[r][c] = ((mazeLine.charAt(c) ==' ')?CLEAR:WALL);
                    }
                }

                // The entrance and exit must not be blocked
                assert(maze[entrance.r][entrance.c]!=WALL && 
                       maze[exit.r][exit.c]!=WALL);

                // The creature is at the entrance
                creature = entrance;



        }

        public boolean goNorth()
        {
            // Location north of the creature
            Location north = creature;
            north.r--;
            // if north is inside of the maze and the square
            // at north is not a wall, we can move the creature
            if (insideMaze(north) && square(north) != WALL)
            {
                creature = north;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean goSouth()
        {
            // Location south of the creature
            Location south = creature;
            south.r++;
            // if south is inside of the maze and the square
            // at south is not a wall, we can move the creature
            if (insideMaze(south) && square(south) != WALL)
            {
                creature = south;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean goWest()
        {
            // Location west of the creature
            Location west = creature;
            west.c--;
            // if west is inside of the maze and the square
            // at west is not a wall, we can move the creature
            if (insideMaze(west) && square(west) != WALL)
            {
                creature = west;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean goEast()
        {
            // Location east of the creature
            Location east = creature;
            east.c++;
            // if east is inside of the maze and the square
            // at east is not a wall, we can move the creature
            if (insideMaze(east) && square(east) != WALL)
            {
                creature = east;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean isOut()
        {
            return (creature == exit);
        }

        public void showPath(OutputStream out)
        {
            // =there is a path
            boolean success = false;

            // Look for the path recursively
            findPath(creature,success);

            // print the path (if we found one0
            if (success)
            {
                System.out.println(this);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "There is no solution path");
            }

            // Remove the VISITED and PATH marks
            // (set such squares to CLEAR)
            for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
                {
                    if (maze[i][j] == PATH || maze[i][j] == VISITED)
                    {
                            maze[i][j] = CLEAR;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public <ostream> ostream leftShift(ostream out, Maze m) 
        {
            // X: wall
            // C: creature
            //  : empty square
            // .: path leading to the exit

            // character on the square
            char l;
            for (int r = 0; r < m.row; ++r)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m.col; ++c)
                {
                    switch (m.maze[r][c])
                    {
                    case CLEAR:
                    case VISITED:
                        l = ' ';
                        break;
                    case WALL:
                        l = 'X';
                        break;
                    case PATH:
                        l = '.';
                        break;
                    }
                    // Check for the creature
                    if (r == m.creature.r && c == m.creature.c)
                    {
                        l = 'C';
                        System.out.println(l);
                    }

                }

            }
            return out;
        }




        public void markSquareAsVisited(Location l)
        {
            assert 0 <= l.r && l.r < row && 0 <= l.c && l.c < col;
            //assert[][] maze != WALL;

            maze[l.r][l.c] = VISITED;
        }

        public void markSquareAsPath(Location l)
        {
            assert 0 <= l.r && l.r < row && 0 <= l.c && l.c < col;
            //assert[][] maze != WALL;

            maze[l.r][l.c] = PATH;

        }

        public int square(Location l)
        {
            assert 0 <= l.r && l.r < row && 0 <= l.c && l.c < col;
            return maze[l.r][l.c];
        }

        public boolean insideMaze(Location l)
        {
            return (l.c >= 0 && l.c < col && l.r >= 0 && l.r < row);
        }

        public void findPath(Location l, Boolean success)
        {
            // This square is being visited
            // Mark it as such
            markSquareAsVisited(l);

            // If it is the exit square, we are done
            // Mark the square as part of the path
            // set success to true
            if (l == exit)
            {
                success = true;
                markSquareAsPath(l);
                return;
            }

            // try all possible moves from this square
            // north, south, east and west
            Location north = l;
            north.r--;
            Location south = l;
            south.r++;
            Location east = l;
            east.c++;
            Location west = l;
            west.c--;

            // If we haven't found the winning path yet and we can go north
            // and we haven't been there already, look for the winning path
            // starting from north
            if (!success && insideMaze(north) && square(north) != WALL && square(north) != VISITED)
            {
                findPath(north,success);
            }
            // If we haven't found the winning path yet and we can go south
            // and we haven't been there already, look for the winning path
            // starting from south
            if (!success && insideMaze(south) && square(south) != WALL && square(south) != VISITED)
            {
                findPath(south,success);
            }
            // If we haven't found the winning path yet and we can go east
            // and we haven't been there already, look for the winning path
            // starting from east
            if (!success && insideMaze(east) && square(east) != WALL && square(east) != VISITED)
            {
                findPath(east,success);
            }
            // If we haven't found the winning path yet and we can go west
            // and we haven't been there already, look for the winning path
            // starting from west
            if (!success && insideMaze(west) && square(west) != WALL && square(west) != VISITED)
            {
                findPath(west,success);
            }

            // If success is true, this location is part of a 
            // solution path. Mark the square as part of the path.
            if (success)
            {
                markSquareAsPath(l);
            }
        }

}
```

And this is how my Location Class looks like:

```
public class Location implements LocationInterface
{
    // store a location in the maze
    // r and c are the row and column of the location in the maze
        public int r;
        public int c;

        // Comparison of 2 locations
        public boolean equalsTo(Location l)
        {
            return (r == l.r && c == l.c);
        }

        public boolean notEqualsTo(Location l)
        {
            return (r != l.r || c != l.c);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line (in your Maze class):

```
Scanner readFile = new Scanner (filename);
```

Does not read from a file in filename - it reads the file name itself as if it were the input.   You instead want to open the file and read that.  Try instead:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
Scanner readFile = new Scanner (fis);
// be sure to fis.close() later
```

Comment: In the stack trace, look at the exact line number.  Is it still Maze.java:38 ?  Probably not.  See which line is now causing the problem.

Comment: different lines but same codes   
line 39: FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

Comment: Gotcha.  Except there is no way that's still throwing a InputMismatchException.  Please do some studying on how Java stack traces work and take a bit more time to understand them.  The answer is there, just need to eke it out a bit more. (I realize that reply might not get my answer accepted, but in the long run it will help you ;)

Comment: hey that is true but if you could point me in the right direction, i will really appreciate it. im knida stuck right now

Comment: (Hint, if the line that is throwing an exception on is ...new FileInputStream() then the exception it's throwing is not going be InputMismatchException, since that step is just opening the file.  Without any other data, my first guess would be that the file doesn't exist.)

Comment: Yep i fixed that. i had the file in another folder. but for some reason, now it just shows a blank screen. If you could please help me to read the file correctly read the content of the file into the maze[][], i will be able to do the rest on my own.

Comment: Sorry dude, ain't got time for that right now.  Try narrowing the issue down a bit and post a new question (that is a different problem after all...)